# Clarification on Healing with Curse of Living Death - Bones Mystery

Tags: pathfinder-2e, oracle

The **Minor Curse** description for the Oracle's *[Bones](https://2e.aonprd.com/Mysteries.aspx?ID=3) Mystery* states:

> [...] Non-magical effects that would restore your Hit Points only grant you half as many HP as normal.

I'm confused about whether *resting* counts as a non-magical effect, as the word effect usually refers to actions, items or spells. If it does count, then does this mean that every single day the Oracle uses a focus spell they get reduced healing from rest (since you only lose the effects of the curse after resting and making daily prep.)? Or am I missing something? This seems a pretty big deal in the long run.

Moreover, the entry on [Resting](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=534) states:

> [...] The character regains Hit Points equal to their Constitution modifier (minimum 1) multiplied by their level. If they rest without any shelter or comfort, you might reduce this healing by half (to a minimum of 1 HP). [...]

The fact that other factors can already halve you HP regen makes this even more complicated. What if the two things are happening at the same time, do you only regain one quarter of the usual HP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Bones seems to affect resting

There is some leeway in the definition of [Effects](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=350) that kind of implies that Effects are only the result of something done, *but* it also notes that Effects includes results caused by the environment.

> Anything you do in the game has an effect. Many of these outcomes are easy to adjudicate during the game. If you tell the GM that you draw your sword, no check is needed, and the result is that your character is now holding a sword. Other times, the specific effect requires more detailed rules governing how your choice is resolved. Many spells, magic items, and feats create specific effects, and your character will be subject to effects caused by monsters, hazards, the environment, and other characters.

So, regardless of if you consider resting something your character does with the Effects listed or the resting period an effect of environmental factors, Bones should reduce the healing received by half.

### Doubling your halving is far less clear

Unfortunately, the only rules we have on halving effects is [Doubling and Halving Damage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=339) (protip: it says round down) and there is no universal rule for 'stacking effects', only [die roll modifiers](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=315). Expect table variance, but I would absolutely apply both effects to cause 1/4 resting healing.

---

### It's not as big of a deal as you may think

While it's true that you could be receiving half or less healing overnight, for most people this will not be a concern. Most parties should have some form of engine that allows them to fully heal before laying down for the night, much of which is magical.

- Anyone with [Medicine](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=57) Trained that can reliably hit a 15 (including the Bones Oracle)

  - It will be halved for the Oracle but they/you can try every hour or 10 minutes with the [Continual Recovery](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=771) Feat
- All [Good Champions](https://2e.aonprd.com/ResearchFields.aspx?ID=2) gain Lay on Hands
- Any Bard with the [Hymn of Healing](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=728) (1st level) or [Soothing Ballad](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=391) (14th level) Feats
- A [Leaf](https://2e.aonprd.com/DruidicOrders.aspx?ID=2) Druids with access to a berry supply
- A Ranger with the [Soothing Mist](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1769) (4th level) Feat
- A Life Mystery Oracle with the [Greater Revelation](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=771) (12th level) Feat

As well as a number of other options that are not infinite, but may provide end-of-day healing if resources aren't used up such as healing font clerics and Alchemists that know Elixir of Life for Quick Alchemy.

---

Postscript, I did find one instance in which this **might be** fairly punishing. The otherwise excellent spell [*moment of renewal*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=201) heals based on your Resting recovery rate (doubled due to 24 hours aka 'long term rest'). Because it lets "targets experience a day's worth of recovery in an instant." and "The targets regain Hit Points and recover from conditions as if they had taken 24 hours of rest", it would require GM ruling whether that is 'magical healing' or 'resting healing'. Personally, I would reduce it per the Curse.

Comment: Thanks! As for it being a big deal or not , many of the healing methods you cited rely on positive healing and damage Undead. The Oracle mystery benefit grants it the choice of being healed as Undead, so relying on these methods seem to make the mystery benefit rather useless. In my specific case I was planning on making a necromancer Oracle, so I could use this benefit and use the Harm spell to heal my PC and my minions in combat at the same time. This would make me rely only on my own healing methods in general right? Do you think in this case the healing reduction for rest is a bigger deal?

Comment: @LucasBaldo Somewhat, but there are other negative healing options (including Evil Champion's version of Lay on  Hands) and many of these are untyped (Hymn is fast healing, Soothing Ballad is not Positive, nor is Goodberry). Additionally, there's still no reason why the basic "Put bandages on it till you feel better" Treat Wounds wouldn't work for you, and you are automatically Trained for having the Bones Mystery. The first few levels will be difficult, but as soon as you have Continual Recovery, you are basically self-sufficient in that regard.

Comment: Continual Recovery does seem like the better option to me now. Thanks for the input! Also Treating wounds in the morning after daily preparations seems way more efficient.

Comment: Unless you think you have to worry about ambushes, or have a reason to get going quickly (it could take an hour or more if you're particularly hurt) in the morning

Answer (score 0):

The question is entirely moot because **resting removes the effect of your curse**. As per the [Oracular Curse feature](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=14):

> Once your minor curse has manifested, it remains in effect until you rest for 8 hours and again make your daily preparations.

And as per the rules for [Rest and Daily Preparation](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=472):

> Once every 24 hours, you can take a period of rest (typically 8 hours), after which you regain Hit Points equal to your Constitution modifier (minimum 1) times your level.

So yes, resting is considered a non-magical effect, but it's irrelevant. When you Rest, you regain HP after the 8 hours have passed, at which point the effect of your curse is gone. **You will regain your HP as normal.**

Comment: Cool answer, but Rest and Daily Preparation describes that Daily Preparations happen in the hour after resting. It seems like the healing from resting would apply before the curse has been lifted with daily prep.